# Adding row requirement to an IF, AND, VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

The formula I have is

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP($U7335, '2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$T:$T,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP($E7334,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$F,1,FALSE)),"Match", "No Match")
```

What it is currently doing is seeing if the numbers in those cells are in my other spreadsheet. But what I want to add is the condition that those numbers also have to be in the same row. Is there any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `index/match`.

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: @findwindow do you know what that would look like with my code?

Comment: Actually, you can just add `match` to your `and`. `match(u7335,contractst:t,0)=match(e7334,contractsf:f,0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP($U7335, '2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$T:$T,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP($E7334,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$F,1,FALSE),--(match($U7335,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$T:$T,0)=match($E7334,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$F,0))),"Match", "No Match")
```

*(complete soln based on key component suggested by @findwindow, main comments)*